# What datatype for generic database fields

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to run over all the fields of a row returned by ExecuteReader(), see here:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"select * from People;", conn);
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (rdr.Read()) 
{
    foreach (Object i in rdr) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i.ToString() + " ");
    }
}
```

This outputs to the console:

```
System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal
```

What should I put instead of object, as some of the fields are numerical (probably being internally cast to int) and some arevarchar (probably being internally cast to string). I did try `string` but that throws an error on the numerical fields. Likewise, using type `var` won't compile.

Thanks.

Comment: are you wanting to know the datafield values that are returned..?

Comment: Yes, the contents of each field: rdr[0], rdr[1], etc.

Comment: based on your reader code.. are you getting any valid data back dotancohen..? what does your sql statement look like as well..

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question with the SQL query and the output. That should have been there to begin with!

Comment: @AndrewBarber you mean "override", not "overload".

Comment: @phoog **facepalm** Of course! oops!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you iterate `foreach (object i in rdr)` you are iterating the rows, not the columns.  See [the documentation for the data reader's `GetEnumerator()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader.getenumerator.aspx).  That's why the ToString override is returning `System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal`: you're calling `ToString()` on the whole data record, not just one of its values.

To iterate the *values* of the reader's *current row*, call the `GetValues()` method instead; this <s>returns an array of objects corresponding to</s> populates an array of objects with the values for the current row:

```
while (rdr.Read())  
{
    var items = new object[rdr.FieldCount];
    rdr.GetValues(items);
    foreach (object i in items)  
        Console.WriteLine(i.ToString() + " "); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Interestingly I am getting a `No overload for method 'GetValues' takes 0 arguments` error, I will go through the docs to see why. One question, though: if in the `while` body rdr refers to the whole data record and not just a single row, then why does rdr[0] return the value of the first field of the currently-iterated row? I do not see that addressed in the docs.

Comment: Ah, sorry, you need to pass in an array which is populated with the values.  I've edited the answer to account for that.

Comment: @dotancohen The indexer `rdr[0]` returns a value of the reader's current row; the enumerator returned by `GetEnumerator()` enumerates the rows.  Why?  It seems very inconsistent.  I've always considered it to be a poorly conceived, confusing design; if someone else has evidence to the contrary I'd be happy to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when you execute a query you know exactly the number of columns, their names and their types. I could see a situation where the number or columns returned changes, or even their names, but not the types. You could add some logic as such ([using these helpful extensions](http://dpatrickcaldwell.blogspot.com/2009/10/strongly-typed-getvalue-extension.html)):

```
   while (reader.Read())
    {
        var myObj = new MyType()
        {
            MyNumberValue = reader.GetInt32(0),
            MyStringValue = reader.GetString(1)
        };
        var optValue = default(string);
        reader.TryGetValue("optColName", out optValue);
        myObj.OptionalString = optValue;
    }
```

this will build an object of `MyType` for every row.

```
    private class MyType
    {
        public int MyNumberValue { get; set; }

        public string MyStringValue { get; set; }

        public string OptionalString { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Juan. The blog post that you linked to is brilliant. An interesting solution, to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Lets imagine you have 3 fields in your table

```
        Id     int,
        Name   nvarchar(64),
        Family nvarchar(64),
        Salary bigint
```

Now you have to read each fields

```
        var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr.Read()) {
            if (!(rdr["Id"] is DBNull))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(rdr["Id"] + " ");
            }
            if (!(rdr["Name"] is DBNull))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(rdr["Name"] + " ");
            }
            if (!(rdr["Family"] is DBNull))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(rdr["Family"] + " ");
            }
        }
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks, Saber, but that assumes that one knows the field names. I am looking for a way to run a foreach on the returned fields without knowing what they are. The use case is that I run `SELECT * FROM` on several tables while testing and debugging, so a generic case to print the values is needed. Thanks.

Comment: Its not possible my friend, at least you should know number of fields per tables to access value of fields by ordinal numbers like `rdr[0]`.

Comment: Thanks, Saber, at least we tried. Voted up for DBNull, I did not know about that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`i.ToString()` calls the `.ToString()` method (which is virtual) on whatever class `i` happens to be implemented by in that iteration.

If i is an integer with a value of 5, it should print "5" (because Int32 overrides `.ToString()` to return the integer value formatted as a String).

If i is a String with a value of "New York", it should print "New York" (because `String` overrides `.ToString()` to return `this`.

EDIT: Apologies, I missed that you were iterating the rows, not the fields.  Try this:

```
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (rdr.Read()) 
{
    for (var v = 0; v < rdr.FieldCount; v++)
        Console.WriteLine(rdr[v].ToString() + " ");
}
```

Comment: Yes, of course I tied the code. The value `System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal` is printed to the console. That looks to me the datatype and not the value!

Comment: Updated, sorry about that.  Missed that you were iterating the rows, not the fields.

Comment: Thanks, Chris, I did not know about the `FieldCount` property. That is very useful, I don't think that is even available in other environments that I work in.

Answer (score 1):

you could also do something like this for example say you want to get a list of all the column names but don't know the names based on the DataReaders return ..
you could create a List

List lstColumns = new List();

```
for (int intCounter = 0; intCounter < reader.FieldCount; intCounter++)
{

  lstColumns.Add(reader.GetName(intCounter));
  columns.Add(string.Join(",",reader.GetName(intCounter).ToArray().ToString().ToList()));
  Console.WriteLine(lstColumns[intCounter]);
}
```

dispose of the lstColumns as well when you are done with it..

this will give you a comma delimited List for FieldNames then if you want to append the data based on the same construct to the List do the following

that's if you want only the field names does this make sense..?

Comment: Thanks, CRAZE! Have you any idea what type List should be? I tried `System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal` but that is a protected type and I cannot make a List out of it. Also, should the variable `columns` in the line before `Console.WriteLine()` actually be `lstColumns`?